# Finding an image within a div in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find out how to use to Descendent Selector to select an image within a div. The methods I've tried haven't worked out for me as I cannot set it to a variable or just select an image. For reference here is the code

```
    <div class="avatar">
        <img src="https://www.khanacademy.org/images/avatars/svg/aqualine-sapling.svg" width="150">
        <h1>Aqualine</h1>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $("<img>").animate({
    width: "400px",
    marginLeft: "30px",
    borderWidth: "10px"    
        
    }, 1500)
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't add brackets to the selector. It should be just `$('img')` or `$('.avatar img')`.

Comment: Thanks, simply adding the img next to .avatar worked.